# Why is $C_V$ used in this derivation?

Tags: thermodynamics, adiabatic

In his [lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DeNBWsZHXTE) (26:30-38:40), Shankar derives the adiabatic pressure-volume relationship $P_1V_1^\gamma = P_2V_2^\gamma$, where $\gamma = C_P / C_V$, from the First Law of Thermodynamics $\Delta U =Q - W$.

His first step in doing is is to make the substitution $\Delta U = n C_V \Delta T$ into the First Law. In adiabatic processes, volumes are not held constant, so why is using the specific heat at constant volume $C_V$ valid?

---

Glossary of Notation

$P$ - pressure

$V$ - volume

$T$ - temperature

$U$ - internal energy

$Q$ - heat added to system

$W$ - work done by system

$C_P$ - specific heat at constant pressure

$C_V$ - specific heat a constant volume

$n$ - number of moles

Comment: As the process is adiabatic, the first law reads $0 = q = \Delta U + p \Delta V$. Also $dU = q_V$ if only work of expansion is considered and volume is constant. And $q_V = C_V dT$. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Notice that if only p-V work is allowed: $dU = q - pdV$, and if V is constant $dU = q_V$. This is valid even if you have a process that is not performed at constant volume.

Comment: @user1420303 Volume is NOT constant, so why is that substitution valid?

Comment: Interesting! Thank you for your spot-on answer. Does this imply $C_V = \frac 32 N_A k_B$ (in per-mole units) for an ideal gas?

Comment: Not sure why so many answers were downvoted, even if they say the same as the accepted answer

Comment: They are only related.

Comment: @Andrei the upvoted answer is the only one that actually justifies the validity of the substitution. The other ones just provide the substitution.

Comment: I don't think you read the answer carefully. What does $\Delta U$ "depends only on temperature. So it's the same as the heat exchange in a process where the work is 0" mean to you? When $W=0$?

Comment: In thermodynamics, the heat capacity at constant volume is defined in terms of the change in internal energy (not heat) with temperature. But, for an ideal gas, the internal energy is a function only of temperature. Therefore, for an ideal gas, the equation ΔU=nCvΔT applies at all temperatures, independent of volume.

Comment: @andrei As someone who had never seen $\Delta U = nC_V \Delta T$ before, the connection wasn't evident, which makes the explanation insufficiently thorough. An explanation that doesn't provide sufficient tools to bring the reader along to the end is just as useful as one that doesn't reach the end.

Comment: Were you referring to what Andrei wrote or to what I wrote?

Comment: @Trevor I call $\Delta U=nC_V\Delta T$ [the cruelest equation](http://john.maloney.org/cruelest_equation.htm) because of how often new practitioners of thermodynamics are tripped up by its application.

Comment: @Chester Miller "the heat capacity at constant volume is defined in terms of the change in internal energy (not heat) with temperature." I think this is the engineering approach. Keenan's $Thermodynamics$ does it like this. But physicists usually define it as heat input per unit temperature rise at constant volume, or equivalent. I've checked in Zemansky, Pippard, Callen.

Comment: @PhilipWood  For a process that involves no work (constant volume) the two are equivalent.  But, since Cv is a physical property of the material rather than a function of process path (i.e., a function of state), I hope you agree that it makes no sense to define heat capacity in terms of Q, since Q depends on process path.  By that rationale, the heat capacity of a material experiencing and adiabatic expansion would be zero.

Comment: But I said "heat input per unit temperature rise $at constant volume.$ The last phrase pins down the process. Surely we both agree that $nc_v$ is $equal to$ the heat input per unit temperature rise at constant volume? I choose to $define$ $c_v$ in this way; you define it from $U=nc_v \Delta T.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$C_v$ is defined for a gas by$$Q=nC_v\Delta T$$
in which $Q$ is the heat inflow needed to raise the temperature of the gas by $\Delta T$ at constant volume.

At constant volume, no work is done, so the First Law collapses to
$$\Delta U = Q.$$
Therfore$$\Delta U = nC_v\Delta T.$$
But for an ideal gas, $U$ is proportional to $n$ and $T$, *whatever sort of process* the gas is undergoing. There is therefore a process-independent proportionality constant. But we know from the constant volume process that this constant is equal to $C_v$ ! We name the constant after just one of the roles that it plays.

[This is a perennial cause of confusion to students learning thermodynamics. I find the following comparable case instructive…
The fundamental role of the space-time constant, $c,$ is as a scale factor between times and displacements, so, for example we can write the invariant interval as$$(c\Delta \tau)^2=(c\Delta t)^2-[(\Delta x)^2+(\Delta y)^2+(\Delta z)^2]$$Yet we call $c$ "the speed of light", after one of the roles that it plays.]

Comment: This does not answer the question. You can't derive the ideal gas adiabatic isentropic relations for a constant volume process, and $\Delta U = nC_v \Delta T$ even if the process is not constant volume.

Comment: @Drew (a) "This does not answer the question." Clearly we disagree. The key paragraph in my answer is the one that starts "But for an ideal gas…". (b) "You can't derive the ideal gas adiabatic isentropic relations for a constant volume process" Who is claiming that you can? (c) "ΔU=nCvΔT even if the process is not constant volume." Exactly so, as I try to explain in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

He started with the first law

$\Delta U = \Delta Q - P \Delta V$

and then noted that $\Delta Q = 0$ for the adiabatic process, therefore we have

$0 = \Delta U + P \Delta V$

Now, for an ideal gas, we know that $\Delta U = nC_v \Delta T$. Therefore

$0 = nC_v \Delta T + P \Delta V$

and this was the basis of the rest of his derivation.

Comment: Typo fixed; question still stands.

Comment: @TrevorKafka This still answers your question... For an ideal gas, $\Delta U = nC_v \Delta T$. That is why it was used. It is valid even if the process is not constant volume.